# How to Handle Redirects for my Login Page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have recently moved from localhost to my live website. I have a simple PHP login page. After the users details are checked with my mysql table and if the username exist and they provide a valid password for that username they are redirected to the home page. I was using the header function built in to PHP but this seems to be no longer working now that I am on my live website.

After further research it seems that I cannot use header tags after the page loads. So I am not echo'ing out script tags to `window.location` redirect to my homepage. The problem with this is that when the new location is being redirected to it appears to look like an additional web pages is loading in before my actual webpage that I'm wanting to go to loads in (This is probably due to the fact that I have extra error handling code that is running after the fact). Does anyone else experience this when using this method? Is there a better way to handle this?

This is what I'm using currently just in case there is any confusion

```
echo '<script>window.location.href = "home.php";</script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was using the header function built in to PHP but this seems to be
>   no longer working now that I am on my live website.

Headers must be the very first thing that your script outputs or they won't work. PHP has a convenience feature called [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) which temporarily holds back the output until the script is done. This allows you to put calls to `header()` anywhere in your code, and then PHP will automatically take care of moving headers to the front of the output for you. Thus, if you have output buffering enabled, you can put headers anywhere and it will still work. If you do not have output buffering enabled, you must put headers at the very start.

I will wager that you are generating output before the headers, and your local PHP install has output buffering enabled, while your remote host does not. You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Update your code to ensure that nothing is output before calls to `header()`.
- Enable output buffering on your host by setting `output_buffering = 1` in your php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I recently learnt you can do this with a meta tag:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com/" />`